# test each object in a list against every other object in the same list exactly once using python

Tags: python, c, loops, for-loop, foreach

To highlight what I am trying to do here is the equivalent in C code.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i )
{
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < COUNT; ++j )
    {
        foo( i, j );
    }
}
```

...where COUNT is the size of the list and 'foo' is a function which takes two different entries in the array.

Many Thanks
DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something in your question, but I believe this is a solution.

```
 for i in range(0,COUNT):
    for j in range(i+1,COUNT):
        foo(i,j)
```

If you want to store the results you could also do the whole thing in a list comprehension:

```
[[foo(i,j) for j in range(i+1,COUNT)] for i in range(0,COUNT)]
```

which is probably more pythonic and definitely faster.

Comment: `for j in range(i+1, COUNT)`